# BeginRead buffer size (heavy CPU load)

Tags: c#, networking

My async tcp client-server app is working for now.

But I have some CPU heavy load issues. If I set network buffer to 8192 it works fine for small messages but if I transfer over 1MB my CPU load is really high.. I can fix it by setting buffer to 81920.

Any solution to fix this? I want to transfer data from a few KB to hundred MBs.

Is it good idea to have multiple TCP connections each with different buffer size? Any other solutions?

It's also possible that my code has some performance issues.

My read code:

```
private class ReadClientState
    {
        public TcpClient Client { get; set; }
        public byte[] Buffer { get; set; } // buffer size...???

        public byte[] inc_message { get; set; }
        public int inc_message_size  { get; set; }
    }
```

BeginRead callback:

```
private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ReadClientState state = (ReadClientState)ar.AsyncState;
        int cbRead = 0;
        try
        {
            cbRead = state.Client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            if (ex.InnerException is SocketException)
            {
                if (((SocketException)ex.InnerException).ErrorCode == 10054)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
            return;
        }

// read 4 byte lenght header (new message incoming)
        if (state.inc_message_size == 0)
        {
            byte[] header = new byte[4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(state.Buffer, 0, header, 0, 4);
            state.inc_message_size = BitConverter.ToInt32(header, 0);
        }

// copy buffer to message data array
        byte[] tmp = new byte[cbRead];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(state.Buffer, 0, tmp, 0, cbRead);
        state.inc_message = state.inc_message.Concat(tmp).ToArray();
        state.Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];


        Array.Clear(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length);


// message is complete
        if (state.inc_message.Length >= state.inc_message_size)
        {
            if (state.inc_message.Length > state.inc_message_size)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR.. read more than expected");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("massage size: " + state.inc_message_size.ToString() + " total bytes read: " + state.inc_message.Length.ToString());

                Array.Clear(state.inc_message, 0, state.inc_message.Length);
                state.inc_message_size = 0;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            state.Client.GetStream().BeginRead(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, ReadCallback, state);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your method of parsing the data seems to need very much copy operations. But this should not be related to the buffer size.

Comment: Run under full load and pause the debugger 10 times. In which line does it stop most?

Comment: You could win some CPU time by reusing the old buffer (remove `state.Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];` and  `Array.Clear(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length);`). Worth a shot but I wouldn't know if that's the bottleneck here.

Comment: reusing old buffer did not helped..

Comment: The CPU load is high when BeginRead() is reading from network (does not matter of buffer size) ... the CPU load is high even if network is slow...

Comment: There is *far too much* data copying here. You don't need to copy the header just to convert it to integer. You don't need to copy the data just to concatenate it. You don't need to clear a new byte array when you're going to overwrite it anyway, in fact probably not at all.